# require is working but require_once is not

Tags: php

**Routes.php**

```
use MyMVC\Core\Route;

$route = new Route;
$route->add('/', 'HomeController@index');
$route->add('about', 'AboutController@index');
$route->add('contact', 'ContactController@index');
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Define Constants
 */
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)));
define('APP_PATH', BASE_PATH . "/app");

/**
 * Including the Composer's autoloader
 */
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Load the routes declarations
 */
require_once 'app/routes.php';

/**
 * Bootstrap our application
 */
require_once 'app/init.php';

/**
 * Initialize our beautiful framework
 */
$application = new \MyMVC\Application($route);
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "MyMVC\\" : "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/Controllers",
        "app/Helpers"
    ],
    "files": ['app/routes.php']  // already removed this line
},
```

When using `require_once` it is giving `undefined variable route error` while if i use only `require` it shows the route object.

Why is that so ?

Comment: Something else must be causing the issue, as `The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.`

Comment: Possibly it is being included earlier on in the script so It is not requiring it again?

Comment: @chriz updatd my code. This is all `index.php` is all about.

Comment: add your `composer.json`.

Comment: did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: just ran it and its working. So if this file was already autoloaded then still i should get $route variable available isn't so ?

Comment: It is as described Álvaro G. Vicario in his answer

Answer (score 1):

All symptoms suggest that 'app/routes.php' is included somewhere else before. Since it defines a variable, if such include does not happen in global scope the variable will be local to wherever it's called from.

Apart from using a dedicated debugger like Xdebug, you can use builtin tools to diagnose the issue. For instance, you have [get_included_files()](http://php.net/get_included_files) to get a list of included files in a given point. You can also add [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_print_backtrace) on top of 'app/routes.php' to find out where it's called from.

**Note on updated question and follow-up comment:** if you're trying to auto-load the file and the file gets loaded automatically, I'd say you've just answered your own question. But it's worth noting that auto-loading is intended to be used on functions and class definitions. You have an arbitrary code snippet that defines a variable and —as you've just learnt— since the variable becomes local to the auto-loader method it isn't of much use.

Comment: I had much help with your answer but there is one thing i am trying to find out for many days. I used files autoloading via composer and i loaded routes.php. Doesn't this mean that the routes.php will b available automatically now ?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error only happens when the file is already loaded from other files. That's why it's not loading it again and you are not getting instance of $route object.

E.g,

Let's say 
**file1.php** included **routes.php**

Now if you use:

1. require 'routes.php' (*it will load same file again even already loaded*)
2. requier_once 'routes.php' (*it will not load the file if already loaded, and as you are not getting instance of $route variable, it's mean it's happening*)

Comment: Point 2 says (it will not load the file if already loaded). If that is so, still $route instance should be available.

Comment: but if and only if the file is not loaded in a function or class as variable instance then can only get from there

Comment: yes you can see in my code above the routes.php is not a class nor a function.

Comment: Your simple answer is that use
GLOBAL $route;
and now you will always get that variable even if loaded in any scope.
Hope you get it :)